# Possible fonts for tabs in technical site heading hierarchy

Tags: website-design, fonts, typography, design-principles

As we sort of came to accept as an axiom - the heading fonts for any document should be arranged in an hierarchy, and the hierarchy font choices should make sense and match.

I have a design that looks something like this:

[image]

Clicking on `Item One` opens an `Item One` tab with the heading hierarchy presented.

**Without going into discussion on the validity of the design (but please, by all means, do point it out if you think it's important) - how one would arrange the heading hierarchy?**

It seems to me that it should include the tabs (on both sides) as well, since they serve as headings in concept, but then I have too much - 5 (or 4 if you think that both tabs should have the same styling - which I do).

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your question? Your title doesn't match the content. Also, soliciting a brainstorm session isn't really appropriate for a Q&A site.

Comment: @ZenMaster  I've re-read this question a few times and I can't figure out what you are actually asking.  If you edit this question to be more clear, please flag it for re-evaluation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Why don't you just use breadcrumbs? It's a little series of text links which show how you've drilled down to reach your current location.</strike>

So above "Heading one" is a little link which says Home → Page → Tab 1. Clicking on any of those links brings you to that section, and you always know where you are.

Since breadcrumbs won't work at all:

- Tab: Capitals bold
- Item: mixed case bold
- Heading 1: capitals regular
- Heading 2: maybe mixed-case italic?
- Text: roman

Comment: Isee... no I have to allow tabbed usage for the right part - user will probably have a lot of these open at any one time, breadcrumbs won't let me do it that way.